# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , " when create my object javascript

Tags: javascript, list, object, syntax-error, typeerror

I'm creating a simple object but I gives me a syntax error:

```
 myObjectList[0] = [{"a", "b", "c", "d"}];
```

this is my error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"
```

Comment: Na-na-na-na... the syntax for a [Javascript object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) is `{ key: "value", ... }` and not `{ "value", ... }`.

Comment: What do you want to receive in result?

Comment: That's not the syntax to create an object **with keys and values**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All objects must have keys. You define an object using curly bracers {}.

Basically what you are saying is, add an array with one object that has no keys defined.

If you want an array with the values a,b,c,d you can remove the bracers:

```
myObjectList[0] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

You always define objects with keys:

```
var myObject = {
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : "C",
    "d" : "D",
}
```

Comment: oh thanks, yeah my object it's defined myObjectList = {}, but I don't know how to add values haha!¡!¡!¡!¡!